# How to set the values of a Combobox which programmatically added in a grid

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a grid which for some reasons I added dynamically a combobox. I have done it and working like charm.

The next thing which I am stack is how to set the selection for each row per code.

for example in first row of the gird the combobox I want to has the value X and in the second row I would like to has the value Y.

```
    FormGridControl grid = sender.formRun().design(0).controlName('FormGridControl1');
    ColumnTable columnTable;
    ValueTable valueTable;

    while select * from columnTable
    {
        FormComboBoxControl combo1 = grid.addControl(FormControlType::ComboBox,columnTable.Name);
        combo1.label(columnTable.Name);
        combo1.enumType(enumNum(enumValue));;

        combo1.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormComboBoxControl, SelectionChange),'DynamicComboControl_SelectionChanged',this);

        while select * from valueTable
           where valueTable.ColumnName ==  columnTable.Name
        {
           // at this place I have to set the values of the combo1 for each line of the grid separately.
           // and I have not any idea how I can do this.
        }



    }
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Any code you're working with so we can guide from there?

Comment: Thank you, I just add the code I am working on. I am open to any other aproach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *never* assigns values to grid fields using a loop.

If the data in your field in the grid comes from a field of the datasource then use a bound field (maybe created dynamically by [addDataField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formgridcontrol.adddatafield.aspx)).

```
 fc = grid.addDataField(fbds.id(), fieldNum(MyTable,MyField));
```

If your data field can be computed by some method add a [display method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx).
Added dynamically like this:

```
name = tableMethodStr(MyTable,myMethod);
fc = grid.addControl(FormControlType::ComboBox, ds.name()+'_'+name);
fc.dataSource(grid.datasource());
fc.dataMethod(name);
```

If your data can be edited, then the method must be an [edit method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/aa637541.aspx). Added dynamically the same way as a display method.

Answer (score 0):

IF your grid have not binded to a datasource 
THEN table.cell(col,row).data()...

see tutorial_Form_Table form.

IF your grid have binded to a datasource
THEN create and fill records in the your table and research() the datasource on the form.

---

Use Selection(i) method if you looking method for FormComboBoxControl.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa499256(v=ax.50).aspx

Comment: My grid is binded to a datasource but the new combobox is not. Can you give me an example? I do not get how to use a grid and a table together.

Comment: Why you does not bind? add a temp table as a datasource and join it to your table.

What axapta vertion do you use?